# custom function to filter values in pandas dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, function, filter

I would like to create a custom function to filter a pandas dataframe.

```
def df_filter(df, first_elem, col1, col2, other_elems):
    '''
    df: main dataframe
    first_elem: first element to search
    col1: first column to search for the first element
    col2: second column to search for first element
    other_elements: list with other elements to search for
    '''
    first_flt = df.loc[(df[col1] == first_elem) | (df[col2] == first_elem)]
    second_flt = first_flt.loc[(first_flt[col1] == other_elems[0]) | (first_flt[col1] == other_elems[1])] 
    return second_flt
```

the first filter is to filter the dataframe by searching for the occurrence of the first element in the col1 and col2 and picking these rows to create first_flt and it works.

In the second filter I would like to search for more values provided in a list (other_elems) and filter again.
The crucial point is the nr of items in this list can be different based on what I plug in.
`other_elems = ['one', 'two', 'three']`
or 
`other_elems = ['one', 'two', 'three', four']`

Thefore this part has to be created based on the nr of elements in other_elems:

```
first_flt.loc[(first_flt[col1] == other_elems[0]) | (first_flt[col1] == other_elems[1])...]
```

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Can you provide a small example you would like to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `other_elems` is an iterable, you can use DataFrame [isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) method.

In your example:

```py
second_flt = first_flt.loc[(first_flt[col1].isin(other_elems)]
```

Comment: yes it is an iterable and this works! Thanks.
There is just one extra paranthesis that needs to be removed: 
```second_flt = first_flt.loc[first_flt[col1].isin(other_elems)]```

Answer (score 0):

You just want to create this single filter by combining two individual filters:

```
def df_filter(df, first_elem, col1, col2, other_elems):
    '''
    df: main dataframe
    first_elem: first element to search
    col1: first column to search for the first element
    col2: second column to search for first element
    other_elements: list with other elements to search for
    '''
    filt1 = (df[col1] == first_elem) | (df[col2] == first_elem) # rows where col1 or col2 match first_elem
    filt2 = (df[col1] == other_elems[0]) | (df[col1] == other_elems[1]) # rows where col1 = other_elem[0] or col2 = other_elem[1]
    filt_final = filt1 & filt2
    return df[filt_final]
```